# Infinite Collection of Sets with These Properties

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I passed by this problem in Abbott's "Understanding Analysis", page 11:

> Produce an infinite collection of sets $A_1, A_2, A_3,...$ with the
> property that every $A_i$ has an infinite number of elements, $A_i ∩ A_j = \phi$ for all $i \not= j$ , and
> $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \mathbf N$

1. Finding the solution was not difficult conceptually (that is, if my attempt is correct), but I have no idea how to formulate it.
   My idea is as follows:

   If the question asked for two sets, an answer would be the sets of even and odd numbers. If they're $3$ sets, I would then give $A_1$ all the numbers starting from $1$ and increment $3$ to get $A_1 = \{1,4,7,...\}$, similarly, for $A_2$, starting from $2$ and incrementing by $3$, etc... For $n$ sets, $A_i = \{i, i+n,i+2n,...\}$.

   However, for an infinite number of sets, formulating a more formal solution is confusing to me.
2. My other question is this: Is this the only way to solve this problem, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. My favorite is to give $A_1$ every second natural number,
$$
A_1=\{1,3,5,7,\dots\},
$$
then give $A_2$ every second of the remaining numbers,
$$
A_2=\{2,6,10,14,\dots\},
$$
then give $A_3$ every second of the (still) remaining numbers,
$$
A_3=\{4,12,20,28,\dots\}
$$
and so on. Equivalently,
$$
A_n=\{2^{n-1}k:k\text{ is odd}\}.
$$
Another equivalent formulation is that $A_n$ consists of those positive integers whose binary expression ends with exactly $n-1$ zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the Fundamental Theorem of Artithmetic and Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes. Good luck!

Comment: I failed to get this hint anywhere. Could you elaborate?

Comment: For instance: let $A_1= \{1\}\cup 2\mathbb{N}$. Then let $A_2 = 3\mathbb{N}\setminus A_1$, $A_3 = 5 \mathbb{N}\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)$, etc.